# Why is `npm install` never finishing?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Environment:
Digital Ocean droplet (Ubuntu 18.04)
node (v14.5.0)
npm (v6.14.5)
Installed with nvm (v0.35.3)

I've set up 3 server blocks with nginx for development, staging, and production of the same node project (back end api). I've successfully set up and run the development and staging servers. When I try to run `npm install` on the production server, the install never finishes, and if I run it with `NODE_DEBUG=cluster,net,http,fs,tls,module,timers` to get some logs, it's an endless stream of the stuff below. I let it run for hours and it just continued printing logs like this. The only environment difference between staging and production at the moment is that `NODE_ENV = production` on the production server and `development` on the staging server, and they run on different ports. What's the deal? What do these logs mean and how might I fix this?

```
MODULE 6383: Module._load REQUEST ./data-types/time parent: /home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/data-type.js
MODULE 6375: load "/home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/clean-css/lib/optimizer/level-2/properties/override-properties.js" for module "/home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/clean-css/lib/optimizer/level-2/properties/override-properties.js"
MODULE 6383: RELATIVE: requested: ./data-types/time from parent.id /home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/data-type.js
MODULE 6383: looking for ["/home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib"]
MODULE 6383: load "/home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/data-types/time.js" for module "/home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/data-types/time.js"
MODULE 6375: Module._load REQUEST ./has-inherit parent: /home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/clean-css/lib/optimizer/level-2/properties/override-properties.js
MODULE 6375: Module._load REQUEST ./every-values-pair parent: /home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/clean-css/lib/optimizer/level-2/properties/override-properties.js
MODULE 6375: Module._load REQUEST ./find-component-in parent: /home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/clean-css/lib/optimizer/level-2/properties/override-properties.js
MODULE 6375: RELATIVE: requested: ./find-component-in from parent.id /home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/clean-css/lib/optimizer/level-2/properties/override-properties.js
MODULE 6375: looking for ["/home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/clean-css/lib/optimizer/level-2/properties"]
MODULE 6383: Module._load REQUEST ./data-types/date parent: /home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/data-type.js
MODULE 6383: RELATIVE: requested: ./data-types/date from parent.id /home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/data-type.js
MODULE 6375: load "/home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/clean-css/lib/optimizer/level-2/properties/find-component-in.js" for module "/home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/clean-css/lib/optimizer/level-2/properties/find-component-in.js"
MODULE 6383: looking for ["/home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib"]
MODULE 6383: load "/home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/data-types/date.js" for module "/home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/data-types/date.js"
MODULE 6375: Module._load REQUEST ../compactable parent: /home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/clean-css/lib/optimizer/level-2/properties/find-component-in.js
MODULE 6375: Module._load REQUEST ./is-component-of parent: /home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/clean-css/lib/optimizer/level-2/properties/override-properties.js
MODULE 6383: Module._load REQUEST ./data-types/datetime2 parent: /home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/data-type.js
MODULE 6375: RELATIVE: requested: ./is-component-of from parent.id /home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/clean-css/lib/optimizer/level-2/properties/override-properties.js
MODULE 6383: RELATIVE: requested: ./data-types/datetime2 from parent.id /home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/data-type.js
MODULE 6375: looking for ["/home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/clean-css/lib/optimizer/level-2/properties"]
MODULE 6383: looking for ["/home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib"]
MODULE 6383: load "/home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/data-types/datetime2.js" for module "/home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/data-types/datetime2.js"
MODULE 6375: load "/home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/clean-css/lib/optimizer/level-2/properties/is-component-of.js" for module "/home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/clean-css/lib/optimizer/level-2/properties/is-component-of.js"
MODULE 6375: Module._load REQUEST ../compactable parent: /home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/clean-css/lib/optimizer/level-2/properties/is-component-of.js
MODULE 6383: Module._load REQUEST ./data-types/datetimeoffset parent: /home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/data-type.js
MODULE 6375: Module._load REQUEST ./is-mergeable-shorthand parent: /home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/clean-css/lib/optimizer/level-2/properties/override-properties.js
MODULE 6383: RELATIVE: requested: ./data-types/datetimeoffset from parent.id /home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/data-type.js
MODULE 6375: RELATIVE: requested: ./is-mergeable-shorthand from parent.id /home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/clean-css/lib/optimizer/level-2/properties/override-properties.js
MODULE 6383: looking for ["/home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib"]
MODULE 6375: looking for ["/home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/clean-css/lib/optimizer/level-2/properties"]
MODULE 6383: load "/home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/data-types/datetimeoffset.js" for module "/home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/data-types/datetimeoffset.js"
MODULE 6375: load "/home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/clean-css/lib/optimizer/level-2/properties/is-mergeable-shorthand.js" for module "/home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/clean-css/lib/optimizer/level-2/properties/is-mergeable-shorthand.js"
MODULE 6383: Module._load REQUEST ./data-types/udt parent: /home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/data-type.js
MODULE 6383: RELATIVE: requested: ./data-types/udt from parent.id /home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/data-type.js
MODULE 6375: Module._load REQUEST ../../../tokenizer/marker parent: /home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/clean-css/lib/optimizer/level-2/properties/is-mergeable-shorthand.js
MODULE 6383: looking for ["/home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib"]
MODULE 6375: RELATIVE: requested: ../../../tokenizer/marker from parent.id /home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/clean-css/lib/optimizer/level-2/properties/is-mergeable-shorthand.js
MODULE 6375: looking for ["/home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/clean-css/lib/optimizer/level-2/properties"]
MODULE 6375: Module._load REQUEST ./overrides-non-component-shorthand parent: /home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/clean-css/lib/optimizer/level-2/properties/override-properties.js
MODULE 6383: load "/home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/data-types/udt.js" for module "/home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/data-types/udt.js"
MODULE 6375: RELATIVE: requested: ./overrides-non-component-shorthand from parent.id /home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/clean-css/lib/optimizer/level-2/properties/override-properties.js
MODULE 6375: looking for ["/home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/clean-css/lib/optimizer/level-2/properties"]
MODULE 6383: Module._load REQUEST ./data-types/tvp parent: /home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/data-type.js
MODULE 6383: RELATIVE: requested: ./data-types/tvp from parent.id /home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/data-type.js
MODULE 6375: load "/home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/clean-css/lib/optimizer/level-2/properties/overrides-non-component-shorthand.js" for module "/home/${user}/${app}/prod/node_modules/clean-css/lib/optimizer/level-2/properties/overrides-non-component-shorthand.js"
```